# Model specification issue in Annette J. Dobson book?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model

I was reading "**An Introduction to Generalized Linear Models**" Third edition by Dobson and Barnett, especially the example of **tropical cyclones**, when suddenly something stroke me. The data set have 3 columns (years, season and number of cyclones). So the way I understand this is that I have two explanatory variables (year and season) and one dependent variable (number of cyclones). Typically I would like to ear that *number of cyclones* is a random variable with a Poisson distribution.
Unfortunately in the book, they absolutely don't say that. They say:

Let $Y_i$ denote the number of cyclones in season $i$. Suppose the $Y_i$'s are independent random variables with the Poisson distribution with parameter $\theta$.

This seems completely bogus to me. There are no many $Y_i$, there is one single $Y$ which is the last column of the dataset, right? The $Y_i$ are samples of $Y$. They are not random variables, they are outcomes!

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, outcomes are random variables, in the sense that they are *represented as random variables in the model*.  So the formulation in the book seems OK to me, this is just about language nuances. Important as they are ...

Comment: I need to study more, It seems that [this lecture][1] from university of Pennsylvania by Jason Morton will provide some clarifications. The dataset is in fact a condensed view. You can have one way tables, two ways tables... and I must first study multinomial distributions in those contexts before jumping on the Poisson. My mistake was to think that the dataset can have only one "shape". A typical layout that we can find in machine learning.


  [1]: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLflMyS1QOtxy_mfqNWpH6hWc7lqgSfKZM